# One-Key Macros in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am trying to use One-Key Macros (as was written [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros))

```
(defun toggle-kbd-macro-recording-on ()
  "One-key keyboard macros: turn recording on."
  (interactive)
  (define-key
    global-map
    (events-to-keys (this-command-keys) t)
    'toggle-kbd-macro-recording-off)
  (start-kbd-macro nil))

(defun toggle-kbd-macro-recording-off ()
  "One-key keyboard macros: turn recording off."
  (interactive)
  (define-key
    global-map
    (events-to-keys (this-command-keys) t)
    'toggle-kbd-macro-recording-on)
  (end-kbd-macro))


(global-set-key '[(f1)]          'call-last-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key '[(shift f1)]    'toggle-kbd-macro-recording-on)
```

But when I press Shift-F1 I get error:

> define-key: Symbol's function
>   definition is void: events-to-keys

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `events-to-keys` function seems to be something obsolete. From what I can tell, it should work by just writing:

```
(defun toggle-kbd-macro-recording-on ()
  "One-key keyboard macros: turn recording on."
  (interactive)
  (define-key
    global-map
    (this-command-keys)
    'toggle-kbd-macro-recording-off)
  (start-kbd-macro nil))

(defun toggle-kbd-macro-recording-off ()
  "One-key keyboard macros: turn recording off."
  (interactive)
  (define-key
    global-map
    (this-command-keys)
    'toggle-kbd-macro-recording-on)
  (end-kbd-macro))

(global-set-key '[(f1)]          'call-last-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key '[(shift f1)]    'toggle-kbd-macro-recording-on)
```